# Ayuda para obtener lista sumatorio de listas generadas de manera iterativa

Tags: python, python-2.7

He desarrollado un programa con el que genero una lista en cada ronda de un total de 5 rondas. Estas listas las añado a una lista de listas denominada mi_lista_tot. El código es el siguiente:

```
import random

mi_lista_tot=[]

for round in range(5):
    mi_lista=[]
    mi_lista_tot.append(mi_lista)

    a1=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]
    a2=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]
    a3=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]

    for n in range(len(a1)):
        mi_lista.append(a1[n] + a2[n] + a3[n])

print mi_lista_tot
```

En la salida actual, lo que estoy generando es una lista de listas del siguiente tipo:

```
[[2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3], [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]]
```

Sin embargo, me gustaría que mi_lista_tot lo que generara fuera una lista sumatorio de los valores en cada índice. En este caso:

```
[9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 7, 11]
```

Es lo que no consigo hacer. Agradezco comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin modificar demasiado tu código puedes usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) o [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (que usa un iterador similar a lo que hace `zip` en Python 3, disminuyendo el uso de memoria) junto a `sum` para sumar `a1`, `a2` y `a3` en cada ronda y luego sumar las rondas entre ellas mismas:

```
import itertools
import random

mi_lista_tot=[]

for round in range(5):
    a1=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]
    a2=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]
    a3=[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]

    mi_lista_tot.append([sum(x) for x in itertools.izip(a1,  a2, a3)])

mi_lista_tot = [sum(x) for x in itertools.izip(*mi_lista_tot)]
print mi_lista_tot
```

Si no usaras `a1`, `a2` y `a3` o las listas de cada ronda para nada más podrías hacer simplemente:

```
import itertools
import random

mi_lista_tot = [sum(r) for r in itertools.izip(*[[random.randrange(2) for i in range(8)]
                                                    for _ in range (5*3)])]
print(mi_lista_tot)
```